# Mysql Query issue with join and filter

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have a table which store's Product ID with filter ID. Mapping is one to many. (One product can be associated with many filters). Now i need to fetch records which matches ***all*** criteria. Say for example, I need to fetch products which are having FILTERS 1,5 and 7. I want exact match like products which is mapped to 1 AND 5 AND 7.

Below are the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_to_filter` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `filter_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`filter_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have tried below mentioned query but it is not fetching me the desired result.

```
select distinct p1.product_id, p1.filter_id from product_to_filter p1
join product_to_filter p2 on 1=1
join product_to_filter p3 on 1=1
where
p1.filter_id=1 AND p2.filter_id=5 AND p3.filter_id=7
```

Kindly help me in resolving this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be possible better way to do this, you could use below script as well

```
SELECT distinct p1.product_id
FROM product_to_filter p1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 from product_to_filter p2 WHERE p1.product_id=p2.product_id AND p2.filter_id=2) 
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 from product_to_filter p3 WHERE p1.product_id=p3.product_id AND p3.filter_id=5)  
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 from product_to_filter p4 WHERE p1.product_id=p4.product_id AND p4.filter_id=7)
```

Comment: Hi Jaydip, Query is working, i need distinct rows but it is fetching all.

Comment: @pepAg Is product_id is PRIMARY KEY ?

Comment: @PepAg Just remove `p1.filter_id ` from `select ` statement

Answer (score 1):

Change condition in JOIN:

```
SELECT p1.product_id 
FROM product_to_filter p1
JOIN product_to_filter p2 ON p2.product_id = p1.product_id 
JOIN product_to_filter p3 ON p3.product_id = p1.product_id 
WHERE p1.filter_id = 1 
AND p2.filter_id = 5
AND p3.filter_id = 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXISTS` in combination with counting all filters in `HAVING` clause, so that there must be 3 distinct filters applied in the set `2, 5, 7`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.product_id, p1.filter_id 
FROM product_to_filter p1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM product_to_filter p2 
  WHERE p1.product_id = p2.product_id 
    AND p2.filter_id IN (2, 5, 7)
  GROUP BY p2.product_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p2.filter_id) = 3
  )
```